# Angular js : How to use resolve when using with require js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I am using required-js with angular-js for one of my project to load the script files. In normal scenario with out required-js i used to store controller in a variable and bind resolve to that variable like variable.resolve and in app config i can mention the resolve function.
   But by using required-js i am defining everything in a module. So i am creating the controller module and storing controller there,so am using controller name instead of function.below is my code for config and controller module.I don't want to write my resolve logic in config. It should be in controller file. How can i do with angular js .

```
define(
    ['angular', 'angular-route', 'controllers', 'directives', 'filters', 'services', 'common-controllers', 'common-directives', 'common-helpdesk-feedback-directives', 'common-constants', 'plunker', 'require'],
    function(angular, angularRoute, controllers, directives, filters, services, commonControllers, commonDirectives, commonHelpDeskFeedbackDirectivesModule, plunker) {
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'controllersModule', 'directivesModule', 'filtersModule', 'servicesModule', 'commonControllersModule', 'commonDirectivesModule', 'commonHelpDeskFeedbackDirectivesModule', 'plunkerModule']);
        app.init = function() {

            setTimeout(function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            }, 2000)
        }
        app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    template: '<div align="center"  ><h1>This is default helpdesk page !</h1></div>',
                })
                .when('/list/:view', {
                    templateUrl: '../../themes/ngCus/templates/helpdesk/listing.html',
                    controller: 'listCtrl',
                });

        });
        return app;

    }
);
```

Here my controller module

```
// Define all your controllers here in controller angular module
define(['angular'], function function_name (angular) {
    var controller = angular.module('controllers', []);
    controller.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'This is dashboard default page !';
    }]);
    return controller;
});
```

Comment: This has been asked many times before, the cleanest solution which I'm using in a large enterprise project is [the one suggested by dan wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx).

Comment: Check out [angularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/) that simplify the use RequireJS with AngularJS

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand : that does not solve the problem .. i want to write my code in controller file not in the file where i config my application

Comment: @marcoseu : That article is nicely done for loading script on demand . that does not say about resolve with modular approach

Comment: @PradeepJaiswar what do you mean by "resolve with modular approach"?  angularAMD allow you to create a file and load a controller on demand.  In your example that uses "controllers" module, it will not work after bootstrap.

Comment: @marcoseu : in my current code my controller is a module (not a function - using controller name instead of function). Suppose if i want to write some resolve function i will have to write inside my config file . the question is how can i write my resolve logic inside the controller file. If i have not been using required js (modular approach ) than it would have been very easy var a = function mycontroller .. then a.resolve = function () {} in the controller file it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is an answer

in controller file

```
/*reslve function for listCtrl */
    controllersModule.resolvelistCtrl = function($q, $timeout) {
        /*resolve logic here*/
    };

/*reslve function for otherCtrl*/
        controllersModule.resolveOtherCtrl = function($q, $timeout) {
            /*resolve logic here*/
        };
```

In boostrap file

```
  define(
        ['angular', 'angular-route', 'controllers', 'directives', 'filters', 'services', 'common-controllers', 'common-directives', 'common-helpdesk-feedback-directives', 'common-constants', 'plunker', 'require'],
        function(angular, angularRoute, controllers, directives, filters, services, commonControllers, commonDirectives, commonHelpDeskFeedbackDirectivesModule, plunker) {
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'controllersModule', 'directivesModule', 'filtersModule', 'servicesModule', 'commonControllersModule', 'commonDirectivesModule', 'commonHelpDeskFeedbackDirectivesModule', 'plunkerModule']);
            app.init = function() {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
                }, 2000)
            }
            app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        template: '<div align="center"  ><h1>This is default helpdesk page !</h1></div>',
                    })
                    .when('/list/:view', {
                        templateUrl: '../../themes/ngCus/templates/helpdesk/listing.html',
                        controller: 'listCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            detailsData: controllers.rsolvelistCtrl,
                            otherData: controllers.resolveOtherCtrl
                            /*we can add more here*/
                        },
                    });

            });
            return app;

        }
    );
```